# Hi, I'm trying to align the image e) so that it is below the image b) and immediately after the image d), but I have not got it

Tags: graphics, wide-image

I'm trying to align the image e) so that it is below the image b) and immediately after the image d), but I have not got it.

Do you know how to do it?

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{s_r}
\caption{$S[r]$} \label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{f_r}
\caption{$I[r]$} \label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{c_r}
\caption{$\varepsilon[r]$} \label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}
\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{d_r}
\caption{$\Delta[r]$} \label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}
% ??????
\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{k_r}
\caption{$K[r]$} \label{fig:e}
\end{subfigure}
\medskip
\centering
\caption{Medidas de incertidumbre} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271522/74960 . I'd guess you should add an "empty" `subfigure` to shift figure `e` on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an empty object the same horizontal size as the others.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Start}

\kant[1]

\begin{figure*}[t!]
\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{$S[r]$} \label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{$I[r]$} \label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{$\varepsilon[r]$} \label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip

\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{$\Delta[r]$} \label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{$K[r]$} \label{fig:e}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\makebox[0.30\textwidth]{}

\caption{Medidas de incertidumbre} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure*}

\kant[2-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also center the bottom row, by adding half phantoms at the sides and stretching space just a half as in the middle.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Start}

\kant[1]

\begin{figure*}[t!]
\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{$S[r]$} \label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{$I[r]$} \label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{$\varepsilon[r]$} \label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip

\makebox[0.15\textwidth]{}\hspace{\stretch{0.5}}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{$\Delta[r]$} \label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{$K[r]$} \label{fig:e}
\end{subfigure}\hspace{\stretch{0.5}}%
\makebox[0.15\textwidth]{}

\caption{Medidas de incertidumbre} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure*}

\kant[2-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]